# Basic JavaScript create table inquiry

Tags: javascript

I succeeded in creating a very basic (no 'for loops' used, I'm a beginner) table in JavaScript tagged onto an HTML button. *It works perfectly*!

```
<input type='button' value='Table' onclick='createTbl()' />


function createTbl() {

    //set up elements
    tbl = document.createElement('table');
    tr = document.createElement('tr');
    th1 = document.createElement('th');
    th2 = document.createElement('th');

   //contents
    content1 = document.createTextNode('Last Name');
    content2 = document.createTextNode('First Name');

    //append
    row1 = tbl.appendChild(tr);

    row1.appendChild(th1).appendChild(content1);
    row1.appendChild(th2).appendchild(content2);

    //display
    document.body.appendChild(tbl);
}
```

However, when I removed the enclosing function, ... :

```
//same code here but tagging the 'var' with each variable used
```

... everything disappears, leaving only the HTML button! I commented the button out, but no luck here as well.

How come? What is the magic table(t) to make it appear without enclosing it in a function?

Comment: Can you share some more code? It is unclear as to where you moved the table creation code to.

Comment: So are you saying that the code only works when is inside de function? Who calls the function?

Comment: @satchcoder, Yes, the table only displays when enclosed in a function. A button calls the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it only works when it's within a function is because you call it from your onclick button. Otherwise the code is just there and nobody is calling it. Try calling the function when the dom has loaded to ensure everything is loaded (document.onload = createTbl)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The intent was to only create a table without having to enclose it in a function; in short, to create an HTML table using JavaScript only, albeit not the best practice I agree. I was only wondering why nothing displays when the code is not enclosed in a function. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I partly figured out the problem: I forgot I was writing the script inside the head section of the HTML. I think that explained why the button worked flawlessly. So I moved only the code inside the function (coz I wanted it not to be a function) and placed it inside the script tag in the body section and hit refresh. At first nothing happened, until I added these:

```
<div id='table-div'>
    <!--table here-->
</div>
```

script:

```
//display table    
document.getElementById('table-div').appendChild(tbl);
```

And there it was! All that for a single row and two columns!

Out of curiosity, I wondered if it would work having the code back in the head section and applying my new found solutions. So with the code back in the head section, I made this slight change to display the table:

```
//display table
document.body.getElementById('table-div').appendChild(tbl);
```

No cigars here. Perhaps bad JavaScript lingo. Nevertheless, it was still good to find out that div was the magic table(t) my code needed.